# Creating Moodle users and register them on courses programatically

Tags: php, moodle

I need to create users and register users on Moodle from the outside. The Moodle database is really complex and it have like 0 documentation. So far I understand that the mdl_users have the users, but I don't get what to query there, and the courses are a headache.

Comment: See answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35881584/using-moodle-create-users-and-enroll-them-in-courses-via-sql/35912777#35912777

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you add "php" to your tags, so I'll give you the php answer, but the query work in any mysql.

```
$servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$dbname = 'moodle';

$u_moodle = 'theusernameyouwant';
$hp_moodle = password_hash('thepasswordyouwant', PASSWORD_DEFAULT); ///IMPORTANT!
$name = 'first name';
$lname = 'last name';
$email = 'e@m.ail'; ///This have to be verified by you as we're inserting it directly
$course = '123'; //Id that you put in moodle admin, not the real id    

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$sql = "INSERT INTO 'mdl_user' (auth, confirmed, mnethostid, username, password, firstname, lastname, email)
    VALUES ('manual', 1, 1, '$u_moodle', '$hp_moodle', '$name', '$lname', '$email')";
// auth = 'manual', confirmed = 1, mnethostid = 1 Always. the others are your variables

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "OKTC";
} else {
    ////Manage your errors
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $m_user WHERE email='$email'";
$result = $conn2->query($sql);
if($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $id = $row['id']; //Id of newly created user. we're using that for to register him on the course
}

////You have to use this if your idnumber for the course is the one you put into moodle (thats not the real id)
$sql = "SELECT id FROM 'mdl_course' WHERE idnumber=$course";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if(!$result){
    ///Not existing course, manage your error
}
if($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $idcourse = $row["id"];
}

///I need now the "enrol" id, so I do this:
$sql = "SELECT id FROM 'mdl_enrol' WHERE courseid=$idcourse AND enrol='manual'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if(!$result){
    ///Not enrol associated (this shouldn't happen and means you have an error in your moodle database)
}
if($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $idenrol = $row["id"];
}

///Lastly I need the context
$sql = "SELECT id FROM 'mdl_context' WHERE contextlevel=50 AND instanceid=$idcourse"; ///contextlevel = 50 means course in moodle
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if(!$result){
    ///Again, weird error, shouldnt happen to you
}
if($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $idcontext = $row["id"];
}

///We were just getting variables from moodle. Here is were the enrolment begins:

$time = time();
$ntime = $time + 60*60*24*$duration; //How long will it last enroled $duration = days, this can be 0 for unlimited.
$sql = "INSERT INTO 'mdl_user_enrolments' (status, enrolid, userid, timestart, timeend, timecreated, timemodified)
VALUES (0, $idenrol, $id, '$time', '$ntime', '$time', '$time')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
} else {
    ///Manage your sql error
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO 'mdl_role_assignments' (roleid, contextid, userid, timemodified)
VALUES (5, $idcontext, '$id', '$time')"; //Roleid = 5, means student.
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
} else {
    //manage your errors
}
```

E finito. There you got a new user name enroled into course 123.

Comment: Works like a charm! thank you!. Is there a way to enrol in "all courses"?

Comment: This is a really terrible idea - Moodle has lots of great built-in database functions that protect you from all sorts of SQL injection attacks that this script fails to address and which will work with any database backend supported by Moodle. Using mysql commands directly like this will almost certainly cause problems in the future (e.g. this script will break immediately if a user has the surname "O'Connor")

Comment: I'm not saying its a good idea, I'm answering the question. real_escape_string($name); solve that issue

Comment: I agree with davosmith, @Aschab there are also triggers in Moodle when creating a user, inserting records via sql doesn't account for this. htmlguy: I've seen this same question being asked several times recently. Are you the same user? I have already answered this several times now. You need to use web services not sql directly -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35881584/using-moodle-create-users-and-enroll-them-in-courses-via-sql/35912777#35912777

Comment: This answer appears to [have been duplicated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36075976).