# Moodle external services login

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

I'm looking to list all courses with External Service and use the Moodle's url provided by the web service to show courses. When I tried to access this url I have this message "You are not logged in". I want to log in before showing this page.

Is it possible to request an authentication token or something I can use to authenticate before showing any Moodle page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable web services.

Have a look at this answer, it shows how to get a token then call an external function

[Using MOODLE create users and enroll them in courses via SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35881584/using-moodle-create-users-and-enroll-them-in-courses-via-sql/35912777#35912777)

For your case though, you will need to use the function  core_course_get_courses

See the documention for the parameters and results at 
http://www.yourmoodlesite.com/admin/webservice/documentation.php